# How to set height of the webpart?

Tags: web-part

How to set height of the webpart to 4 inches? I tried following but not working.

```
PageViewerWebPart pvwp = new PageViewerWebPart();
pvwp.Title = strTitle;
pvwp.Height= "4 Inch";  // Should be "4in" and now works
pvwp.ChromeType = PartChromeType.TitleAndBorder;
webpartManager.AddWebPart(pvwp, strZone, ZoneID);
```

Comment: it should be "4in" and now it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN, you should use a 2 character code for [WebPart.Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.height.aspx)

```
pvwp.Height = "4in";
```